# Grouping by month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table. The date format is YYYY-MM. I need to find the monthly averages of this stock price, meaning that I have to find the average price of this stock in January, February, etc. I was thinking of using the groupby function but failed to do so. Any help would be appreciated

```
    Date    StockPrice
0   1970-01 360.319048
1   1970-02 346.723684
2   1970-03 327.345714
3   1970-04 319.852727
4   1970-05 270.375238
... ... ...
475 2009-08 118.430952
476 2009-09 119.055714
477 2009-10 122.239546
478 2009-11 125.273500
479 2009-12 128.896364
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your values to datetime data format, then you can apply groupby as per your needs:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m', errors='ignore')
df.groupby('Date').mean()
```